# Layout for MapView

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview

Hello there android experts, I have a problem for some time and after some workaround, I can't achieved what I want.

I just want to have a layout (not sure what the name of it) that is similar to the Map application on android:

Here's the image of the layout:

[image]

How to achieve / call this kind of layout if you are in a MapView?
Is it possible?

Comment: You'll have to recreate this by hand... You cannot access another APK's layouts as far as I know...

Comment: thanks for the reply, I know how to make that layout but my problem is invoking that layout (layout gain focus) inside my layout view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on examining this in Hierarchy View, it would appear that your panel is a separate activity, themed with a translucent background so the underlying activity shows through.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, i thought if i would call another activity within an activity, it will then animate to the activity that is being called, so there is no use if i will have a semi translucent background...

Comment: @scamexdotexe: Use `overridePendingTransition()` to control that.